# $\liminf_{n\to\infty} g_n(x)\ge 0$ for all $x>0$ implies $\liminf_{n\to\infty} g_n(x_n)\ge 0$ for some $x_n\to 0$?

Tags: analysis

As the title suggests, the problem is: if $\liminf_{n\to\infty} g_n(x)\ge 0$ for each $x>0$, then we may choose a sequence $\{x_n\}$ such that $x_n\to 0$ and $\liminf_{n\to\infty} g_n(x_n)\ge 0$. Intuitively, this is right as long as $x_n$ tends to 0 sufficiently slow. But how to *rigorously* show this? Thanks!

Comment: Could you be a bit more precise about your $\inf$? What is it on, the $n$ or the $x$?

Comment: Corrected. Thank you for your interest!

Answer (score 1):

For all $x$ and all $\epsilon>0$, there are only finitely many $n$ with $g_n(x)<-\epsilon$.

For $k\in\mathbb N$, let $y_k=\frac1k$ (or virtually any sequence with $y_k\to 0)$ and let $m_k$ be the least integer such that $g_n(y_k)>-\frac1k$ for all $n>m_k$.
Now let $\nu_1=0$ and recursively $\nu_{n+1}=\min\{\nu_n,m_{n+1}\}+1$.
Then $\nu_k\to +\infty$ strictly monotonically.
Especially, for each $n$ there exists a maximal $k$ with $\nu_k\le n$. Let $x_n=y_k$ with this maximal $k$.
Then $x_n\to 0$ because $(\nu_k)$ exceeds every $n$ soner or later.
More proecisely, given $\epsilon>0$ we find $K$ such that $|y_k|<\epsilon$ for all $k>K$. Then for $n>\nu_{K+1}$ we have $x_n=y_k$ with $k>K$, hence $|x_n|<\epsilon$. In other words, $x_n\to 0$.
Since $x_n=y_k$ with $n\ge \nu_k>m_{k}$, we have $g_n(x_n)=g_n(y_k)>-\frac 1k$.
Thus if $\epsilon>0$ is given, we have $g_n(x_n)>\epsilon$ as soon as $n>\nu_{\lceil\frac1\epsilon\rceil}$. In other words, $\liminf_{n\to 0} g_n(x_n)\ge0$.